# Bootstrap multiselect used in a Bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

when I use multiselect independently, it works well.

but when I put it in a bootstrap dropdown-menu, as we know, if we click on the dropdown-menu, it's window will be closed.

so I use stopPropagation() to stop click event progating to dropdown-menu, however, by doing this, the multiselect failed working, while the 'test'   can call the function test() correctly.

my code is as follows:

```
<ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
  <li>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='row' id='filter-container'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <h4><a onclick='test();'>test</a></h4>
          <select id='example-getting-started' multiple='multiple'>
            <option value='aaaaaa'>bbbbbb</option>
            <option value='cccccc'>cccccc</option>
            <option value='dddddd'>dddddd</option>
            <option value='eeeeee'>eeeeee</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>




$('#filter-container').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: What is your test() function?

Comment: @Ctc test() is a simple alert. function test(){alert('1');}

Answer (score 0):

I came upon the same problem, and found [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) bootstrap plugin that takes care of all that. It'll keep the dropdown open for a multiple select. The snippet seems to have issues pr

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/master/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/master/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

The snippet seems to have issues presenting the mutliselect properly.

Comment: well, my scene is when I put the bootstrap-select or bootstrap-multiselect in a dropdown-menu, it fails to work as the outer container would be closed.

Answer (score 0):

conclusion:

@see  [dropdown source link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js)

the dropdown event will proppagating to document as

```
$(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-menu', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(jQuery);
```

so there has no method to put multiselect in a Bootstrap dropdown-menu.